# CrawlerProcess as Airflow operator causing spider to start repeatedly

Tags: python, scrapy

```
DAG:
with DAG('lv_usa_market',
         default_args=default_args,
         description="scraper for LV usa market",
         schedule_interval="0 8 * * *",
         start_date=datetime(2022, 2, 18),
         render_template_as_native_obj=True,
         catchup=False,
         tags=["usa", "LV"],
         ) as dag:
    task_lv_usa = ScraperOperator(
        task_id='task_lv_usa',
        market='usa',
        brand='lv',
    )
=====
OPERTOR:
class ScraperOperator(BaseOperator):
    def __init__(self, *, brand, market, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.market = market.upper()
        self.brand = brand.lower()

    def execute(self, context: Dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
        from units.lv import mySpider

        settings = get_project_settings()
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        process.crawl(mySpider, market=self.market)
        process.start()
=====
SPIDER:
class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'LV'

    def start_requests(self):
        if self.market == 'USA':
            self.entry = 'https://lv_link_to_usa/'
            self.ccode = 'USD'
            self.currency_id = 1
            self.tax_rate = 0
            self.precision = 0
        self.result = []
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.entry, callback=self.parse)
        print self.result

    def parse(self, response):
        ... parse response ...
```

I am trying to use Airflow to schedule scraping for products info from some brands thru scrapy, however I encountered a problem, the log file generated from Airflow grows very fast to GBs slowing my laptop to a halt! Inside the logfile is just a repeating line:

> 2022-04-29 11:07:25 [airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance] WARNING: 2022-04-29 11:07:25 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: scrapybot)

> 2022-04-29 11:07:25 [airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance] WARNING: 2022-04-29 11:07:25 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: scrapybot)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, have you resolved this issue?

Comment: No, not when using CrawlerProcess, I am using runner to call the spider and reactor to start/stop the runner, that works.